# pop and push the elements in the array based on click and non click of bootstrap cards in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having 6 bootstrap cards in my web page where the details of the card are id and content.For example when I click the 1st card the details of the first card should be pushed into the array when I again click the 1st card the details of first card should be popped.
My html code is:

```
<div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(1)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_1" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_1"><b>I am redecorating</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(2)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_2" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_2"><b>I am moving</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(3)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_3" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_3"><b>I need help with a layout</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(4)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_4" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_4"><b>I am looking for species</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(5)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_5" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_5"><b>I am moving in someone</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(6)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_6" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_6"><b>other</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My JS CODE IS

```
var goal = []
function getGoal(id ,content){
  if (goal == []) {
    for(var i=0; i<goal.length; i++){
      if(goal[i].id == id) {
        var index = goal.indexOf(goal[i])
        if (index !== -1) {
          goal.splice(index, 1);  
        }
      }else {
        var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
        var x = JSON.stringify(data);
        goal.push(x)
      }
    }
  }else {
    var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    goal.push(x)
    console.log(goal)
  } 
}
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
```

By this jS code it is working so far is pushing the elements into the goal array when I again clicks the same card also pushing of elements is being done but not pop How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code. check it out:

```
    var goal = []
    function getGoal(id, content) {
        if (goal.length > 0) {
            var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
            var x = JSON.stringify(data)
            var index = goal.indexOf(x)
            if (index == -1) {
                goal.push(x)
                console.log(goal)
            }
            else {
                goal.splice(index, 1)
                console.log(goal)
            }
        }
        else {
            var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
            var x = JSON.stringify(data)
            goal.push(x)
            console.log(goal)
        }
        //to Store in localstorage 
        localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal))

        // To get all ids
        var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
        var goalIds = []
        if (storedNames)
            storedNames.forEach(element => {
                element = JSON.parse(element)
                goalIds.push(element.id)
            });
        console.log(goalIds)
    }
```

Comment: it worked but  how do i get the values in local storage can you please say?

Comment: @madhavi updated code to store in local storage.
`localStorage.setItem("goal", goal)`

Comment: When I set in the local storage using              
            localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal));                                                      My array is getting as ["{\"id\":2,\"content\":\"I am moving\"}"] why that slashes are coming

Comment: @madhavi it's double stringified because you are also doing `var x = JSON.stringify(data)` so if you again stringify whole goal array it will add slashes

Comment: Ya I got the data into local storage now I need to get the items which are clicked into another variable from local storage can you please say this?

Comment: @madhavi check code. updated to get goal data from local storage

Comment: when I click the cards again the data is popping from the local storage but not popping from storedNames variables in console. why is this occuring can you please say this?

Comment: My requirement is from the local storage I should get only ids which iam clicking not the content can you say the loop how can I write for this?

Comment: @madhavi means you don't want to save content in local storage only ids?

Comment: @ waseem No i want to save content and id in local storage but while getting from localstorage I want only ids into one new variable

Comment: @ Waseem I had updated according to your code I am getting this error                            Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 38
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @madhavi forget to stringify goal befor storing in localstorage. check again

Comment: @ waseem Now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
this error is coming

Comment: @madhavi please try again. copy entire code it will work

Comment: @ Waseem I had tried it worked fine but when it is going to local storage the storedNames array not updating simultaneously when I refresh the page then the storedNames array is getting the ids why like this?

Comment: @madhavi because for storednames getting data from local storage outside of function that's why not updating untill refresh page. i placed it inside function check it now.

Comment: @ waseem Thank you very much it really worked fine one last doubt every time the element popping and pushing the storedNames array is repeatedly printing in console why?

Comment: @ Waseem one last requirement I need to print these ids in the html form field value based on onload() function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  getting error as Uncaught ReferenceError: goalIds is not defined.Just say cant I access this goalids out of the function in another function get that ids in form field value onload of form